# Is there "best practice" for referencing Spring MVC mappings (annotations) in JSPs

Tags: spring, jsp, dry, spring-annotations

I've got a Spring web application that I've inherited and now I'm extending. I've lived through the hell of massive, sprawling Spring XML files and a refactoring process - time I'll never get back. I'm now starting to write new Controller code using annotations.

I've got Controllers with the RequestMappings defined as annotations and I've put my URLs in as final static in the Controller so I can reference them as return values elsewhere in the code. However, that all seems to hit the wall when trying to build JSPs.

Is there an accepted "Best" way to do this? (or any way at all?)

To illustrate....

```
public class MyController {
    /**
     * Magic string that defines the base URL for this action
     */
    public static final String BASE_URL = "/do_my_smart_action.do";
    /**
     * Magic string defining parameter name
     */
    public static final String PARAM_ID = "id";

...

    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_URL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView beginSmartAction(
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = PARAM_ID) Long id,
        ModelMap model) {

        // Do clever stuff

        return new ModelAndView(TARGET_JSP_NAME, model);
    }

}
```

and I'd like in my jsp to be able to write URLs something like...

```
<a href="<${BASE_URL}?${PARAM_ID}=${object.id}">Do Smart Action</a>
```

If I change the definition of the BASE_URL in the code, I want the links in the JSP to "just work".

For the record, I'm currently on Spring 3.0.6, Java 1.5 and glassfish 3.1.2. The former can be bumped relatively easily. Some strange things seem to happen with the code if I try to move to java 1.7 so shifting that might be more of a problem.

Any advice will be gratefully received.

Comment: Partially answering my own question... Further investigation suggests that http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/Journal200601.jsp#a3 is a place to look

Comment: 1) Use `@Controller` annotation for your controllers, no need of XML configuration.  2) You're not setting `BASE_URL` as a key/value pair in your `ModelMap model`, how do you expect to access to it in your view (similar for other ELparameters)? You can create a method that will always add your constants to your model. It's up to you how to design it.

Comment: 1) I know. I inherited this and I'mr efactoring to use annotations (amongst other things). 2)Thanks for that. As ever, the key is in the question and the bits I managed to leave out. The problem is linking to _**this**_ controller from jsps driven by others. So if I have a Foo object (and associated controller and jsps) that contains a set of Bar objects and I want to link from the Foo JSP to the Bar JSP. From what you've said, I've realised that the solution is to add the URLS from the _target_ controller into the `ModelMap` for the _source_ controller

Comment: Can you view not simply reference its own URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute("baseUrl")` which simply returns `BASE_URL` and it will make it accessible in the jsp as `${baseUrl}`. But that will work only for pages that are rendered via this controller. Other controllers will have different `${baseUrl}`, and it will get confusing.

I think you don't actually need that. Having the url hardcoded in the jsp is not that much of a problem - it just won't be that easy to refactor (but it will still be pretty easy - just search and replace).

If you really feel you will need these, you can have all the URL constants extracted into one class, which is an interceptor `HandlerInterceptor`, and there you can fill them all in the model. E.g.

```
public class ControllerUriPopulatingInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {
   public void postHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView model)
            throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("usersBaseUrl", USERS_BASE_URL);
    model.addAttribute("articlesBaseUrl", ARTICLES_BASE_URL);
    ....

   }

   ...
}
```

You can see that this class will at some point contain hundreds of constants. Calculate the pros and cons and decide whether you need this or not.